# Show traffic density like overlay on Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a bunch GPS points and network signal strength data which I want to show up on the map like traffic overlays (not points, but discrete segments along the road). What is the best way to do it? Using Mapbox platform.

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: @jmkiley: Mapbox.

Comment: Which Mapbox SDK are you using?

Comment: Sorry. Using JavaScript.